# How to unset nested array with ArrayObject?

Tags: php, arrayobject

[ideone](http://ideone.com/NHi5k)

### Sample Code:

```
<?php
$a = new ArrayObject();
$a['b'] = array('c'=>array('d'));
print_r($a);
unset($a['b']['c']);
print_r($a);
```

### Output

```
ArrayObject Object
(
    [b] => Array
        (
            [c] => Array
                (
                    [0] => d
                )
        )
)
ArrayObject Object
(
    [b] => Array
        (
            [c] => Array
                (
                    [0] => d
                )
        )
)
```

You notice that `$a['b']['c']` is still there, even after unsetting. I would expect `$a` to have just the one value left (`b`).

In my actual app, I get the following warning:

> Indirect modification of overloaded element of MyClass has no effect

Where `MyClass` extends `ArrayObject`. I have a lot of code that depends on being able to unset nested elements like this, so how can I get this to work?

Comment: Sadly you won't be able to get those calls to `unset` to work since `ArrayObject::offsetGet` returns a copy.  I've left you w/ a drop-in replacement for those calls below though, hopefully it saves you some time!

Comment: OK, I take this back, must have been debugging hastily or something earlier today, have a look at my latest edit.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

One way to do it

```
<?php
$a      = new ArrayObject();
$a['b'] = array('c' => array('d'));
$d      =& $a['b'];

unset($d['c']);
print_r($a['b']);
```

prints:

```
Array
(
)
```

Would have to think a bit longer for an explanation as to why the syntax you've originally used doesn't remove the element.

**EDIT: Explanation of behavior**

What's happening is the call to `unset($a['b']['c']);` is translated into:

```
$temp = $a->offsetGet('b');
unset($temp['c']);
```

since `$temp` is a copy of `$a` instead of a reference to it, PHP uses copy-on-write internally and creates a second array where `$temp` doesn't have `['b']['c']`, but `$a` still does.

**ANOTHER EDIT: Reusable Code**

So, no matter which way you slice it, seems like trying to overload `function offsetGet($index)` to be `function &offsetGet($index)` leads to trouble; so here's the shortest helper method I came up w/ could add it as a static or instance method in a subclass of `ArrayObject`, whatever floats your boat:

```
function unsetNested(ArrayObject $oArrayObject, $sIndex, $sNestedIndex)
{
    if(!$oArrayObject->offSetExists($sIndex))
        return;

    $aValue =& $oArrayObject[$sIndex];

    if(!array_key_exists($sNestedIndex, $aValue))
        return;

    unset($aValue[$sNestedIndex]);
}
```

So the original code would become

```
$a      = new ArrayObject();
$a['b'] = array('c' => array('d'));

// instead of unset($a['b']['c']);
unsetNested($a, 'b', 'c');
print_r($a['b']);
```

**YET ANOTHER EDIT: OO Solution**

OK - So I must have been scrambling this morning b/c I found an error in my code, and when revised, we can implement a solution, based on OO.

Just so you know I tried it, extension segfaults..:

```
/// XXX This does not work, posted for illustration only
class BadMoxuneArrayObject extends ArrayObject
{
    public function &offsetGet($index)
    {   
        $var =& $this[$index];
        return $var;
    }   
}
```

Implementing a Decorator on the other hand works like a charm:

```
class MoxuneArrayObject implements IteratorAggregate, ArrayAccess, Serializable, Countable
{
    private $_oArrayObject;  // Decorated ArrayObject instance

    public function __construct($mInput=null, $iFlags=0, $sIteratorClass='')
    {
        if($mInput === null)
            $mInput = array();

        if($sIteratorClass === '')
            $this->_oArrayObject = new ArrayObject($mInput, $iFlags);
        else
            $this->_oArrayObject = new ArrayObject($mInput, $iFlags, $sIteratorClass);
    } 

    // -----------------------------------------
    // override offsetGet to return by reference
    // -----------------------------------------
    public function &offsetGet($index)
    {
        $var =& $this->_oArrayObject[$index];
        return $var;
    }

    // ------------------------------------------------------------
    // everything else is passed through to the wrapped ArrayObject
    // ------------------------------------------------------------
    public function append($value)
    {
        return $this->_oArrayObject->append($value);
    }

    public function asort()
    {
        return $this->_oArrayObject->asort();
    }

    public function count()
    {
        return $this->_oArrayObject->count();
    }

    public function exchangeArray($mInput)
    {
        return $this->_oArrayObject->exchangeArray($mInput);
    }

    public function getArrayCopy()
    {
        return $this->_oArrayObject->getArrayCopy();
    }

    public function getFlags()
    {
        return $this->_oArrayObject->getFlags();
    }

    public function getIterator()
    {
        return $this->_oArrayObject->getIterator();
    }

    public function getIteratorClass()
    {
        return $this->_oArrayObject->getIteratorClass();
    }

    public function ksort()
    {
        return $this->_oArrayObject->ksort();
    }

    public function natcassesort()
    {
        return $this->_oArrayObject->natcassesort();
    }

    public function offsetExists($index)
    {
        return $this->_oArrayObject->offsetExists($index);
    }

    public function offsetSet($index, $value)
    {
        return $this->_oArrayObject->offsetSet($index, $value);
    }

    public function offsetUnset($index)
    {
        return $this->_oArrayObject->offsetUnset($index);
    }

    public function serialize()
    {
        return $this->_oArrayObject->serialize();
    }

    public function setFlags($iFlags)
    {
        return $this->_oArrayObject->setFlags($iFlags);
    }

    public function setIteratorClass($iterator_class)
    {
        return $this->_oArrayObject->setIteratorClass($iterator_class);
    }

    public function uasort($cmp_function)
    {
        return $this->_oArrayObject->uasort($cmp_function);
    }

    public function uksort($cmp_function)
    {
        return $this->_oArrayObject->uksort($cmp_function);
    }

    public function unserialize($serialized)
    {
        return $this->_oArrayObject->unserialize($serialized);
    }
}
```

Now this code works as desired:

```
$a      = new MoxuneArrayObject();
$a['b'] = array('c' => array('d'));
unset($a['b']['c']);
var_dump($a);
```

Still have to modify some code though..; I don't see any way round that.

Comment: I thought I read somewhere that as long as we don't override `offsetGet` it will return a reference, as `ArrayObject` is implemented in C. Might have been Sam's comment here: http://www.php.net/manual/en/arrayobject.offsetget.php#79496

Comment: This is really unfortunate though... I've got about 340 times where I perform an unset like this sprinkled across my project. I'm not sure it would be safe to try to update them all, plus the core framework at once. I was hoping to keep it backwards compatible with the old array syntax.

Comment: Still have to change calls like `$a = new ArrayObject()` to `$a = new MoxuneArrayObject()`; best I can do to minimize requisite changes.

Comment: That's okay. I've only got one ArrayObject so far, and it's derived (MyClass extends ArrayObject), so I'd just have to extend MoxuneArrayObject instead presumably.

Comment: Nice; well that ought to do it I'd imagine.  Might want to double check the code for typos, heh, I haven't tested every method :)

Comment: I decided to abandon attempting to turn my array into a class. Too many of the `array_*` functions don't work with it. Instead, I'm creating a secondary object that wraps the array (keeping a reference to it).

Answer (score 4):

It seems to me that the "overloaded" bracket operator of `ArrayObject` is returning a copy of the nested array, and not a reference to the original. Thus, when you call `$a['b']`, you are getting a copy of the internal array that `ArrayObject` is using to store the data. Further resolving it to `$a['b']['c']` is just giving you the element "c" inside a copy, so calling `unset()` on it is not unsetting the element "c" in the original.

`ArrayObject` implements [the `ArrayAccess` interface](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.arrayaccess.php), which is what actually allows the bracket operator to work on an object. The documentation for `ArrayAccess::offsetGet` indicates that, as of PHP 5.3.4, references to the original data in `ArrayObject`'s internal array can be acquired using the `=&` operator, as [quickshiftin](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9982055/1304626) indicated in his example.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `unset($a->b['c']);` instead of `unset($a['b']['c']);` in case if there won't be a huge problem to do a such replacement for all same situations within your project

Answer (score 0):

I seem to have a [partial solution](http://ideone.com/vge4u). `unset` seems to work if all the nested arrays are instances of `ArrayObject`. In order to ensure all the nested arrays are ArrayObjects as well, we can derive instead from this class:

```
class ArrayWrapper extends ArrayObject {
    public function __construct($input=array(), $flags=ArrayObject::STD_PROP_LIST, $iterator_class='ArrayIterator') {
        foreach($input as $key=>$value) {
            if(is_array($value)) {
                $input[$key] = new self($value, $flags, $iterator_class);
            }
        }
        parent::__construct($input, $flags, $iterator_class);
    }

    public function offsetSet($offset, $value) {
        parent::offsetSet($offset, is_array($value) ? new ArrayWrapper($value) : $value);
    }
}
```

(updated for recursiveness; untested)

And then whenever you try to add a nested array, it will automatically get converted to an `ArrayWrapper` instead.

Unfortunately many of the other array functions, such as `array_key_exists` don't work on ArrayObjects.